# mysql jdbc driver does not support delimiters in triggers with multiple statements

Tags: mysql, jdbc, triggers

i've got some code that is triggering a syntax error because of some misplaced semicolons. if this was running on the command line, i'd solve this with a delimiter. unfortunately, the jdbc4 driver doesn't seem to recognize delimiters. anyway to get this to run?

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER obs_update BEFORE UPDATE ON obs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF OLD.voided = 0 AND NEW.voided = 1 THEN
      DELETE FROM clinic_obs WHERE id = OLD.obs_id;
   ELSE
      UPDATE clinic_obs SET clinic_obs.revision_token = NOW()
      WHERE NEW.obs_id = clinic_obs.id;
   END IF;
END;
|
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 6):

Delimiter is a command for SQL client. There is no need to use delimiter in JDBC. 
Example below shows it:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TriggerExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        Connection con = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "login",
                    "password");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("CREATE TRIGGER obs_update BEFORE UPDATE ON obs "
                    + "FOR EACH ROW "
                    + "BEGIN "
                    + "IF OLD.voided = 0 AND NEW.voided = 1 THEN "
                    + "   DELETE FROM clinic_obs WHERE id = OLD.obs_id; "
                    + "ELSE "
                    + "   UPDATE clinic_obs SET clinic_obs.revision_token = NOW() "
                    + "   WHERE NEW.id = clinic_obs.id; "
                    + "END IF; "
                    + "END;");
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the semi colon after the final END word. so it looks like this:

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER obs_update BEFORE UPDATE ON obs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF OLD.voided = 0 AND NEW.voided = 1 THEN
      DELETE FROM clinic_obs WHERE id = OLD.obs_id;
   ELSE
      UPDATE clinic_obs SET clinic_obs.revision_token = NOW()
      WHERE NEW.obs_id = clinic_obs.id;
   END IF;
END|
```

It should work because I have done a similar trigger/procedure using jdbc driver.