# How to create a trigger for mysql 5.5.44?

Tags: java, mysql, syntax-error, mysql-5.5

```
s = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName +"\n" +
    "(\n" +
    "    " + tablelower + "_currentid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,\n" +
    "    " + tablelower + "_id VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,\n" +
    "    " + tablelower + "_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,\n" +
    "    " + tablelower + "_type VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,\n" +
    "    " + tablelower + "_topic  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,\n" +
    "    " + tablelower + "_pin VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,\n" +
    "    " + tablelower + "_device VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,\n" +
    "    " + tablelower + "_device_id INT NOT NULL,\n" +
    "    FOREIGN KEY(" + tablelower + "_device_id) REFERENCES Devices(device_currentid)\n" +
    ");\n" +
    "\n" +
    " delimiter | \n" +
    " CREATE TRIGGER " + tablelower + "_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON " + tableName + 
    " FOR EACH ROW\n" +
    " BEGIN\n" +
    "   SET new." + tablelower + "_id = CONCAT('" + topic + "',LPAD((SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = '" + tableName + "'),4,'0'));\n" +
    "   SET new." + tablelower + "_topic = CONCAT((SELECT device_topic FROM Devices WHERE device_name LIKE new." + tablelower + "_device),'/',(new." + tablelower + "_id));\n" +
    " END;\n" +
    " | \n" +
    " delimiter ;";

    mysqlconn.createStatement().execute(s);
```

Above is the Code which will make a table and a trigger for it with the given name to tableName and tablelower which are string variables. This is the first version i wrote and i was getting the error below:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter | 
CREATE TRIGGER tablename_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON tablename FO' at line 14
```

After google help I've found this thread [Error while creating trigger through JDBC on mysql5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899306/error-while-creating-trigger-through-jdbc-on-mysql5-5) and the doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html and i've changed my code to a StringBuilder to this:

```
            tableCreation.append("CREATE TABLE " + tableName);
            tableCreation.append("(");
            tableCreation.append(tablelower + "_currentid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,");
            tableCreation.append(tablelower + "_id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,");
            tableCreation.append(tablelower + "_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,");
            tableCreation.append(tablelower + "_type VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,");
            tableCreation.append(tablelower + "_topic  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,");
            tableCreation.append(tablelower + "_pin VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,");
            tableCreation.append(tablelower + "_device VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,");
            tableCreation.append(tablelower + "_device_id INT NOT NULL,");
            tableCreation.append("FOREIGN KEY(" + tablelower + "_device_id) REFERENCES Devices(device_currentid)");
            tableCreation.append(" ); ");

            tableCreation.append("DELIMITER // ");
            tableCreation.append(" CREATE");
            tableCreation.append(" TRIGGER " + tablelower + "id_trigger ");
            tableCreation.append(" BEFORE INSERT");
            tableCreation.append(" ON " + tableName + " FOR EACH ROW");
            tableCreation.append(" BEGIN");
            tableCreation.append(" SET new." + tablelower + "_id = CONCAT('" + topic + "',LPAD((SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = '" + tableName + "'),4,'0'));");
            tableCreation.append(" SET new." + tablelower + "_topic = CONCAT((SELECT device_topic FROM Devices WHERE device_name LIKE new." + tablelower + "_device),'/',(new." + tablelower + "_id));");
            tableCreation.append(" END;//");
            tableCreation.append("DELIMITER ; ");

            mysqlconn.createStatement().execute(tableCreation.toString());
```

But still after these changes i get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds  to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'DELIMITER //  CREATE TRIGGER reedswitchid_trigger  BEFORE INSERT
>   ON  ReedSwitches' at line 1.

I am executing this through java and the MySQL server is on a Raspberry pi 2.
For any more info comment and **NOTE that i am a beginner in SQL.** Thanks

**EDIT:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to >your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET >new.lightsensor_topic = CONCAT((SELECT device_topic FROM Devices WHERE >devic' at line 1. Exiting

```
             tabl = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName  +
                "(" + " " + tablelower + "_currentid INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, " +
                tablelower + "_id VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, " +
                tablelower + "_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, " +
                tablelower + "_type VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, " +
                tablelower + "_topic  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, " +
                tablelower + "_pin  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, " +
                tablelower + "_device VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, " +
                tablelower + "_device_id INT NOT NULL, " +
                "FOREIGN KEY(" + tablelower + "_device_id) REFERENCES Devices(device_currentid)" +
                ")";
             trigg=
                " CREATE TRIGGER " + tablelower + "_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON " + tableName + 
                " FOR EACH ROW" +
                "   SET new." + tablelower + "_id = CONCAT('" + topic + "',LPAD((SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = '" + tableName + "'),4,'0'))" +
                "   SET new." + tablelower + "_topic = CONCAT((SELECT device_topic FROM Devices WHERE device_name LIKE new." + tablelower + "_device),'/',(new." + tablelower + "_id))" +
                " END";

        mysqlconn = data.getConnection();
        mysqlconn.createStatement().execute(tabl);
        mysqlconn.createStatement().execute(trigg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC Stateent#executeXXX methods are intended to execute **single** SQL statement, not multiple statements at once.
Even if some databases/driver implementations allow for this, this is a non  standard way, and it is not portable, so simply don't use it.
 
Divide your code into two statements:

```
String s1 = "CREATE TABLE ( ....... )";
String s2 = "CREATE TRIGGER .......END";
 mysqlconn.createStatement().execute( s1 );
 mysqlconn.createStatement().execute( s2 );
```

Two important notes:

- don't use semicolons `;` at the end of SQL commands in JDBC
- don't use `DELIMITER x` command - it is not SQL command, but mysql-client command, the database doesn't recogize it