# How can I change delimeter in jdbc to create procedure?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to create a mysql procedure dynamically using jdbc. To create it, I need to change delimiter first. However, on executing this statement:

```
 DELIMITER $$
```

I am getting error:

> Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.dao.QueryException: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$'
>   at line 1

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267172/mysql-delimiter-error . Let me know if it helps

Comment: @PrabhatG Not related. This issue is more of jdbc not supporting this query.

Comment: can you show us your code please?

Comment: I wonder if you actually need to specify the delimiter

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11899306/2144390