# MySQL create procedure script runs in Workbench but not in java conn.createStatement().execute

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm dynamically creating a database in Java. The database and all it's tables are being created without any problem. But when I try to run a script to create the first stored procedure I get a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` exception. I can run the same script just fine in MySQL Workbench.

**Java:**

```
final String sql = "DELIMITER $$\n" +
                   "CREATE PROCEDURE `app_configs_select_all`()\n" +
                   "BEGIN\n" +
                   "    select config_id,\n" +
                   "        config_name,\n" +
                   "        config_value,\n" +
                   "        config_type,\n" +
                   "        description,\n" +
                   "        client_id\n" +
                   "    from app_configs;\n" +
                   "END $$\n" +
                   "DELIMITER ;";


try (final Connection conn = creationDataSource.getConnection()) {
    conn.createStatement().execute(sql);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Exception:**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `app_configs_select_all`()
BEGIN
    select config' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2594)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2499)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:844)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:748)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
    at com.dc.api.config.ApiConfig.testDataSource(ApiConfig.java:121)
    at com.dc.api.config.ApiConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$634f492e.CGLIB$testDataSource$2(<generated>)
    at com.dc.api.config.ApiConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$634f492e$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cc9cd33a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:355)
    at com.dc.api.config.ApiConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$634f492e.testDataSource(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:618)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:232)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:175)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:224)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:209)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5244)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas why I'd be getting this error?

Comment: Remove delimiter, as it is meant for MySql clients. Your code should work without delimiter in java

Comment: @Ehs4n Thank you, that worked. If you'd like to add that as an answer instead of a comment I'll accept it.

Comment: Sure, I will, with some more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql jdbc driver does not support delimiters in triggers with multiple statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481771/mysql-jdbc-driver-does-not-support-delimiters-in-triggers-with-multiple-statemen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delimiter is a command for SQL client. There is no need to use delimiter in your `Java` code.

You can modify your code to work, like this.

```
final String sql = "CREATE PROCEDURE `app_configs_select_all`()\n" +
                   "BEGIN\n" +
                   "    select config_id,\n" +
                   "        config_name,\n" +
                   "        config_value,\n" +
                   "        config_type,\n" +
                   "        description,\n" +
                   "        client_id\n" +
                   "    from app_configs;\n" +
                   "END";


try (final Connection conn = creationDataSource.getConnection()) {
    conn.createStatement().execute(sql);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```